# Flex: when object has focus highlight parent instead?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a TextInput and a Canvas object both inside an HBox object. When the input text field has focus it highlights, I would like to change this to be the containing HBox that highlights when the Input Text has focus.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do that?

Here is my code:

```
<mx:HBox 
        keyDown="checkKey(event)" 
        horizontalGap="0">
        <mx:TextInput 
            id="searchBox" 
            width="500" 
            fontSize="25" 
            backgroundColor="#F0F0F0" 
            borderThickness="2" 
            borderColor="#666666" 
            borderStyle="solid"/>
        <mx:Canvas 
            borderThickness="2" 
            borderColor="#666666" 
            borderStyle="solid" 
            backgroundColor="#666666">
            <mx:Button 
                label="Search" 
                click="searchInputText()" 
                fontSize="21" 
                styleName="primaryButton"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:HBox>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think HBoxes have highlighting enabled by default. But you could make the HBox respond to the focusIn event: Setting the filter's alpha to 0 makes it completely transparent.

```
<mx:HBox 
    name="parentHBox"
    keyDown="checkKey(event)" 
    horizontalGap="0">
    <mx:filters>
        <mx:GlowFilter alpha=0.0>
    </mx:filters>
    <mx:TextInput 
            id="searchBox" 
            ...
            focusIn="{HBoxGlowFilter.alpha = 1.0}"
            focusOut="{HBoxGlowFilter.alpha = 0.0}"/>
    <mx:Canvas 
            ...>
            <mx:Button 
                    label="Search" 
                    click="searchInputText()" 
                    fontSize="21" 
                    styleName="primaryButton"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:HBox>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to adjust your code somewhat but I got it to do half of what I want..the HBox has a glow now..but I still need to stop the TextInput from glowing as well...Do you know how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: I got it, had to set focusThickness to 0 on the TextInput..thanks.